SWT Rich Text Editor in RCP with Edge browser
For RCP product, Eclipse is upgraded to 4.23 and we have SWT Rich Text Editor for which the default browser is updated from IE to Edge.
Rich Text Editor can add images from local file system. Edge doesn't support  with src value from local file system. Hence, data URL is used for image and text size is increased. With this change, Rich Text Editor takes a long time to load if there is image with data url and hangs.
It works fine with IE.
I don't see similar issue reported. May I know if there is text/content limitation for Edge browser in SWT rich text editor? If not, any pointers to address this issue would be useful.

Have you tried this with the current release, 4.32 (soon 4.33)? It's possible optimizations have been made, and in any case, no one's going to patch improvements into a build 10 releases back.

Are you asking about the Nebula RichTextEditor? You can also ask about that on the Nebula github site issues
